# How to modify PayPal buttons for WooCommerce using PayPal Express Checkout?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

I am currently trying to edit the way the PayPal smart buttons are displayed on my checkout page.
I use WooCommerce, the free [PayPal Express Checkout](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/paypal-express-checkout/) plugin.

At the moment, it looks like this:

https://paste.pics/8T4MP

And I would like it to look like this ( to include the extra option to pay by Debit/Credit Card ).

https://paste.pics/8T4N1

The source code taken from the PayPal website to display the new version is this:

```
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=GBP" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
          shape: 'rect',
          color: 'blue',
          layout: 'vertical',
          label: 'pay',

      },
      createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [{
                  amount: {
                      value: '1'
                  }
              }]
          });
      },
      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
              alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
          });
      }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

Where can I add this code? 
How can I modify the plugin / checkout page?

Thank you very much for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you linked to probably doesn't use Smart Payment Buttons

There is this plugin which does have an option for them: https://woocommerce.com/woocommerce-and-paypal/

So, try that plugin instead, and then once you have the smart buttons working you can see about customizing them

Comment: I am basically speaking about / using the plugin suggested by you.

Comment: Oh I see. PayPal Express Checkout must be an old name for it then

Comment: It looks like this is where it renders the buttons: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout/blob/95c3b0bd1506ab9243a68851b833262536ebd6c7/assets/js/wc-gateway-ppec-smart-payment-buttons.js#L54

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I don't know how to bring the modifications.

Comment: You could start by commenting out the funding section